# Unable to connect to server on local network via new openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I created an openvpn server on AWS using the marketplace AMI, I changed the 'vpn settings' for the network address ad the group default IP both to be `10.0.0.0/20`

I then downloaded the client file and added that into my Ubuntu 18.04 vpn settings via the import option.

After that I tried to ssh into another server found at `10.0.10.220` That failed even though port 22 is wide open (`0.0.0.0/0`)

When checking ifconfig for details about the connection I see the below which is related to the VPN.

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.8.2  netmask 255.255.252.0  destination 10.0.8.2
        inet6 fe80::eac9:76b7:5e88:68e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 141  bytes 7544 (7.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

A note, my local home network is `192.168.X.X` so should be no conflicts

EDIT**

`ip route`

```
default via 10.0.8.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.8.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
10.0.8.0/22 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.8.2 metric 50 
18.204.38.141 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.200 metric 600 
192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static scope link metric 600
```

EDIT 2**
My terraform code

```
resource "aws_instance" "vpn" {
  ami           = "ami-0ca1c6f31c3fb1708"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  key_name = "josh"
  monitoring = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.vpn.id]
  disable_api_termination = true
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public["us-east-1a"].id
  source_dest_check = false

  tags = {
    Name = "VPN"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "vpn_eip" {
    instance = "${aws_instance.vpn.id}"
    vpc = true
}

resource "aws_security_group" "vpn" {
  name        = "vpn"
  description = "Allow vpn traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.Main_VPC.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 943
    to_port     = 943
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 1194
    to_port     = 1194
    protocol    = "udp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

EDIT 3**

Add Jenkins server TF

```
resource "aws_instance" "jenkins" {
  ami           = var.ubuntuAMI
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  key_name = "josh"
  monitoring = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ssh_access.id, aws_security_group.jenkins.id]
  disable_api_termination = true
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public["us-east-1a"].id

  tags = {
    Name = "Jenkins"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "jenkins_eip" {
    instance = aws_instance.jenkins.id
    vpc = true
}


resource "aws_eip_association" "jenkins_eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = "${aws_instance.jenkins.id}"
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.jenkins_eip.id}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "jenkins" {
  name        = "jenkns"
  description = "Allow jenkins traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.Main_VPC.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your routing table? `ip route` is the command. If you look closely, you'll see `0` rx bytes for `tun0`, which indicates an inability for your machine to speak/be spoken to.

Comment: @t3ddftw I added the output of that command to the OP and for my route table I just have a `10.0.0.0/16` to `local` and `0.0.0.0/0` to my internet gateway for that subnet which the vpn is in

Comment: VPN server's private IP address is `10.0.10.163`

Comment: Are you able to ping 10.0.8.1? You have overlapping routes, which might be part of the problem.

Comment: @t3ddftw Yes I can ping that IP - just tested now

Comment: Can you post a `traceroute` to `10.0.10.220`?

Comment: @t3ddftw A trace route to that shows just 1 hop to the gateway / `.1` then just stars after that till I cancel it

Comment: did you check EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck?
https://www.jacobdevans.com/pfsense-in-aws-as-a-vpn-concentrator/

Comment: @JacobEvans yes that is disabled

Comment: what is 10.0.10.220, 
can you ssh to 10.0.8.1 (assumed openvpn gateway), does the server you are trying to access have a route back? (check my post for that)

Comment: @JacobEvans .220 is an EC2 instance. 10.0.8.1 should be the gateway so no chance of SSH into that. I can't ping it either. The server I am trying to access has not much setup yet. It's all in TF, an instance, an eip, a sg with port 22 open, eip association and that's all.

Comment: see my op for more terraform

Comment: @JacobEvans Cool so I changed and followed a different guide and did things manually and VPN to local network is working but no internet access

https://medium.com/@tatianaensslin/how-to-create-a-free-personal-vpn-in-the-cloud-using-ec2-openvpn-626c40e96dab

Comment: @joshk132 for NAT you'll need a iptables/NAT policy setup.

Comment: @JacobEvans Hmm so I have my vpn server in the same subnet as my internet gateway. Don't think I can have multiple routes in my route table as to have both a igw and nat gw. Do I have to move my interget gateway?

Answer (score 1):

**Two issues**

1) You haven't NAT'd the traffic on your vpn server, so other systems need a return route, add this in AWS or make all traffic look like it's coming from the VPN Server

2) You can't Access the Internet as your source IP range (vpn subnet) isn't getting NAT'd on the vpn router

Both cases can be solved by adding this policy to the server running openvpn

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.8.0/22 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables save
```

or

```
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```